# Where should I reference Angular controllers in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

When we develop an application in ASP.NET MVC and Angular we must chose a place to store Angular scripts. Main application file where an Angular module resides is often placed inside Scripts directory and referenced in Layout view.

But what about controllers? Angular controller is usually bound to a view. It's tempting to put it inside scripts section inside the view.

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        'use strict';

        foo.controller('fooBarCtrl',
        ...
```

It's not great idea though because that controller won't be a separate JavaScript file and won't be cached (or even worse - in some cases will be cached even if we don't want it to be).

It's quite common practice to put controllers into `Scripts\Controllers` directory, each controller into separate file. It helps not only to avoid problems with caching but prevents from mixing Razor and JavaScript. It also allows to minify the scripts if we wrap them in a bundle.

My question is - how should we reference those scripts? I've seen examples where all scripts were loaded in the Layout, in a single bundle. It doesn't seem to be the best solution, especially with large projects. Should we wrap each script in a separate bundle and reference it inside scripts section?

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Controllers/fooCtrl.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

What's the best practice for referencing Angular controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.x does not support lazy loading out of the box. I believe this is addressed in v2. So you are either left to load all the scripts at the start, or use something like [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) to enable lazy loading.

Personally I add all my Angular JS code inside a single bundle and load this bundle in the view.